# Open div smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to open div smoothly to full size of its content? If:

1. content of the div - text of any size
2. div initially displays some of the text (`{overflow:hidden; height: 100px;}`)

It should be crossbrowser solution, appearance of scrollbar is unacceptable.

Thanks.

---

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/EwudW/) thanks to @Tryster.

Comment: what do you mean by "smoothly"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603397/jquery-animate-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember the scrollHeight property of an element should return the length of the content. You could then use this to call jQuery.animate on the height.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it with jquery

```
$("#your_div_name").show('slow');
```

or

```
$("your_div_name").slideDown('slow');
```

Comment: Nope, div is visible, but it shows a part of his content (via `{overflow:hidden; height: 100px;}`). I want to increase height of the div smoothly until div began to show all of his content.

Comment: say your parent dive name is `divParent` and insert a div inside the `divParent` say `your_div_name` and do the same.. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/vxS6y/

```
 $('.smooth').slideUp(350).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```