# jQuery div slide down when update

Tags: jquery, html, refresh, slidedown

I have my code here that checks if there is a new post on my image table.

When I have a new post and my timestamp changes, I want a div to slide down saying there are new updates,
like in this picture:

[image: Instagram: 1 new photo]

```
setInterval('checkForUpdates', 30000);
var lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
function checkForUpdates() {
   $.get('image.php?timestamp=' . lastTime
      , function (results) {
         if (results) { /* fade into dom */ }
      }
   );
   lastTime = (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: my question is how do i slidedown a div when jquery check the timestamp of my image.php page! and there is a new update!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the slide down function? http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/
or animate the height from 0 [jQuery animate height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603397/jquery-animate-height)

Answer (score 0):

```
//add the div with the new post text
$("the conatiner id").prepend("<div class = 'new-post' style = 'width: 100%; height = 20px;'> A new post has been added </div>");
//make it slide down
$("the container id").find(".new-post:last").slideDown("fast");
```