# jQuery ajax can't animate div height resize in success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I have a menu in which every item has a content updated via ajax (putted in the "content" div).

```
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="gr" on><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="yel"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li class="bl"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the `$.ajax` `success()` function, where I put the ajax received data in "content" div, I want to resize div height with animate(). here the steps:

1. get the old "content" height
2. update the "content" div with the ajax received data
3. take the new height
4. animate using the height difference.

So I wrote:

```
success : function (data) {
  var contHeight = $("#content").height(); //older "content" height
  $('#content').html(data); //update "content"
  var diffHeight = $("#content").height() - contHeight; //difference from new and old height
  $('#content').animate({height: '+=' + diffHeight + 'px'},500);
}
```

I tried my code (using some `alert()` functions for debugging) and I noticed that: if I use `animate()`, `contHeight` it's equal to the "content" height after the data update(so old height is equal to the new one) and there is no animation. On the other hand, if I remove `animate()` old and new heights are different. Seems that `animate()` doesn't permit the update of the "content" height.

Comment: This question is quite similar to yours: [jQuery animate height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603397/jquery-animate-height)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your content block is float:left; ?
Maybe height of #content doesnt change really ... if you have multiple block with float:left; in a parent block with float:none; , parent block havent "the real height", child blocks were showed because overflow is visible ...

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content" style="float:left">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your animate function to this:

```
$('#content').animate({height: $('#content').height() + diffHeight + 'px'},500);
```